# Como adicionar uma linha no inicio do dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo de Tetris no Windows Forms, já programei os movimentos de todas as peças, me resta agora apagar as linhas que estejam pintadas por completo.

Para remover uma linha uso o código:

```
dgvTetris.Rows.RemoveAt(27);
```

Assim que eu remover uma linha, o meu programa automaticamente deve adicionar uma linha no inicio, oque eu não estou conseguindo fazer.

Segue o código inicial do meu Tetris:

```
private void FrmPrincipalTetris_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable DT = new DataTable(); 
        DT.Columns.AddRange(new[]
        {
            new DataColumn("0"), new DataColumn("1"), new DataColumn("2"), new DataColumn("3"), new DataColumn("4"), new DataColumn("5"), new DataColumn("6"), new DataColumn("7"), new DataColumn("8"), new DataColumn("9")
        });
        string[] Espaco = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
        for(int i = 0;i<=27;i++)
        {
            DT.Rows.Add(Espaco);
        }
        dgvTetris.DataSource = DT; // adiciona a matriz no dataGrid
        //dgvTetris.Refresh();
        for(int i=0;i<28;i++)// pinta as celulas de preto
        {
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                dgvTetris.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        //dgvTetris.Rows.RemoveAt(27);// remove linha
        //DT.Rows.Add(Espaco);

        //DT.Rows.Add(Espaco);
        //dgvTetris.DataSource = DT;
        //dgvTetris.Rows.RemoveAt(27);
        ///dgvTetris.Refresh();
        // dgvTetris.Rows[27].Delete();
        //dgvTetris.Rows.Remove(dgvTetris.Rows[26]);
        ID_Rotacao = 0;
    }
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, só falta isso para eu terminar meu projeto.

Desde já,
Obrigado.

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Consegui! Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para inserir no começo utilize `Rows.Insert()`, passando o índice zero, então os valores das colunas:

```
this.dgvTetris.Rows.Insert(0, "valor coluna 1", "valor coluna 2");
```

Mas isso só iria funcionar se não tivesse usando `DataTable`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx

**No seu caso faça assim:**

```
// crie uma nova linha
DataRow row = DT.NewRow();

// estou adicionando um valor de teste na primeira coluna da linha
row[0] = "teste";

// adicione esse linha na posição zero do DataTable
DT.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
```